# Why Jquery keyup Function Automatically work When Stop Typing and Click Anywhere on Body

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange, keyup

I am using Keyup & change Both together and It's working fine without any issue, But the issue only is when the user stops typing and click anywhere on the body of the page ajax runs again.

Where is the problem, Anybody help me please, below is My Code

```js
$(".eventclass").on('keyup change', function (){

    var txt = $('#search_text').val();
    var st = $('input[type=radio]:checked', '.radiostatus').val();
    var act_id = $('.actid').val();
    var child_id = $('.childid').val();

    if(txt != '' || st !='' || act_id !='' || child_id !='')
    {
        $('#maindiv').hide();
        $("#loadi").show();

        if (globalTimeout != null) {
            clearTimeout(globalTimeout);
        }

        globalTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            globalTimeout = null;
            $.ajax({
                url:"activity_post_load.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{
                    search:txt,
                    status: st,
                    actid: act_id,
                    childid: child_id
                },
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#loadi").hide();
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        $('#results').html('');
        $('#maindiv').show();
    }
});
```

Here is HTML of Page for a better understanding, I am using input and select together

```
 <div class="row fx-wrap">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6">   
    <label class="form-label"> Search Posts</label>  
    <input type="text" name="keysearch" id="search_text" 
    placeholder="Search by sightseeing Name" class="form-control 
    eventclass" placeholder="Search Sightseeing places" />           
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <label class="form-label"> Act_id </label>
    <select name="act_id" class="form-control actid eventclass"> 
    <option value="">PARENT</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <label class="form-label"> Child_id </label>

    <select name="child_id" class="form-control childid eventclass"> 
    <option value="">CHILD</option>
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <div class="radiostatus">
    All <input type="radio" class="status eventclass" name="stat" 
    value="all"><br>
    Status 0 <input type="radio" class="status eventclass" name="stat" 
    value="zero"> <br>
    Status 1 <input type="radio" class="status eventclass" name="stat" 
    value="1">  
    </div>
    </div> 

    </div>

     <div class="table-responsive" id="maindiv"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML, so we can reproduce the issue? Be aware that when the user stops typing, there is still a delay of 2 seconds before the request is made... and when the response arrives, there is another delay of 1 second before the page is updated. So that means there is at least an update following **3 seconds** after the last key action.

Comment: I have added Html of Page in above question

Comment: The `change` event is triggered only when you `blur` on the input, so click on the body in your case.

Comment: If you want to capture copy-paste or autocomplete it's better to use an `input` event which is also the only event that you can use on Android (because keycodes don't work there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by how the `change` event works on an `input` (or `textarea`) element.

Mozilla Contributors [explain it as follows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event):

> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the `change` event fires at a different moment:
>
> [...]
> 4. When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not committed

This is what happens when you click anywhere on the page: at that moment the "uncommitted" change, that was made in the `input` element, is committed, and the `change` event fires.

You can change this behaviour by listening to the `input` event instead of the `change` event. And when you do that, you don't need to listen to the `keyup` event anymore. So:

```
$(".eventclass").on('input', function () {
    // ... rest of code ...
}
```